# Schengen visa cancellation process Netherland

Tags: visas, schengen

I lost my passport with valid Schengen visa issued by Netherland, so I applied new Schengen visa from Hungary for a planned trip, now all documents are in Hungary date and very close to travel date, without cancelling Netherlands issued old visa, new visa can not be issued: as per Hungary embassy. to support have submitted all police documents regarding lost passport. is there a way out to fast track for old visa cancellation.

Comment: Even if your old passport has been lost, the Dutch Schengen visum is still valid. Is there a reason why you didn't contact the Dutch embassy to have it reissued in your new passport instead of applying for a new visum from Hungary?

Answer (score 2):

What you should have done (and probably still can do in time) is to visit the Dutch embassy or consulate with the police report about your lost or stolen passport and your new passport so they can swap the visa to the new passport (and at the same time invalidate it for the old one).

By applying for a new visa instead you are giving the impression that you're trying to game the system to get multiple visa on multiple (possibly fake) passports, never a good idea.